# Speaker fabric cloth

Tags: speakers, diy, material

What's the name of the fabric that's used for covering speakers or what's the closest fabric with similar characteristics that I can use?

Comment: There are all kinds of speaker parts suppliers on the Internet that have cloth specifically designed for speakers. If ordering online is an option, you shouldn't have too much trouble finding the perfect thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, it was called "grille-cloth" and it was made from a coarse-weave of rather thick plastic filaments.  It is still available in many places, particularly those vendors who supply people restoring vintage equipment.

Modern speakers tend to use more conventional material similar to (or identical as) common, inexpensive polyester double-knit.  It is available in dozens of colors (and patterns).  And it is "stretchy" so that it can be stretched over a frame and hold its shape.  We sometimes even sew up a complete "sock" that goes all the way around the speaker enclosure (as for something visible hanging from the ceiling, etc.)

Comment: There is a material called velour, which has the properties you mentioned and it is what we used for speaker covers. If we covered the side of the box it was vinyl over dense foam.

Comment: Velour may be found as a material used for costumes or even covering speaker cabinets. But it is MUCH too thick (and acoustically absorbing) to be practical for any kind of grille cloth.  The primary requirement for grille cloth is ACOUSTIC TRANSPARENCY. For the most obvious of reasons.

Comment: We only used it for woofers, and still had to paint the wood black because Velour is somewhat transparent. We had to stretch it out and glue it down so it would not vibrate with the bass. This was 35 years ago, the 'fun' days.

Comment: Ah, yeah it would bee OK for a sub-woofer. But I wouldn't use it for anything above 200-300 Hz.